# How do you check for duplicate data using Cypress.io?

Tags: html, primeng, cypress

I have a table, using DIVs that contain customer data. I wan't to be able to test if there is duplicate customer data.  Below is an example of my table:

```
<div class="customer-table">
    <div class="row activemember">
         <div class="col-1"><a href="#">Holiday,John</a></div>
         <div class="col-1">8675309</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row activemember">
         <div class="col-1"><a href="#">Doe,Jen</a></div>
         <div class="col-1">123524</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row activemember">
         <div class="col-1"><a href="#">Holiday,John</a></div>
         <div class="col-1">8675309</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm not how to approach this to say that, indeed, there is duplicate data (Holiday, John)

I'm hoping to say that, with Cypress, there "There are duplicates, therefore the step fails.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this to make sure there is only one

```
cy.get('a:contains("Holiday,John")').should('length',1);
```

If this fails you have more than one or none.. I tried it using your HTML and it seemed to work. It is basically counting how many A elements there are that contain Holiday,John. In this case you will get 2 which will fail the test

Comment: Thanks! This helps when there is static data for sure.  I'm further along.   However, is it possible to do this using dynamic data?

Comment: ahhh I see you want to check all the rows to make sure there are no duplicates.. My first thought is your UX test should not being testing for duplicates, that seems more like a back-end API test, but let me ponder on for a minute to think how we can do it.

Comment: Do you have a backend API that is producing this Data? I am assuming there is API of some sort.

Comment: You are correct, there is an api call to get this information.  I see what you mean about testing for dupes in the API.  I will take that approach.  Thanks!

Comment: glad I could help in a small way, I was trying to get to a 1000 reputation and this put me over.